# Log4j %F and %L tokens don't show anything

Tags: tomcat, log4j

I've added log4j to my web app that is hosted in a Tomcat server.

The conversion pattern is : `log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p %d{dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm} (%C::%L) - %m%n`

But there is an issue - when the log message comes from my app's classes, the logger cannot find the file name and line :

```
ERROR 25:11:2011 08:43 (com.example.bl.dataaccess.BLAccessManager::?) - Error on writeGroup
```

Is there a possibility to see a number instead of **'?'** sign ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you used ant to build the classes?

If so, then add `debug="yes"` in target compile and it should fix it.